# Vuejs_ object returns empty in if condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I am trying to give the user certain permissions, but I am unable to access the teamsList object which shows empty in the 'if condition'

output console

[image: output console]

please check this image. The if-condition is not working.

```js
async created() {
  console.log('teams list is before loading teams',this.teamsList);
    this.loadTeams()
      .then((response) => {
        this.teamsList = response.data;
         console.log('teams list is after loadteams',this.teamsList);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      
      if (this.teamsList.teamName==='admins') {
      this.haveAccess=true
      console.log('access-check',this.teamsList.teamName);
    } 
  console.log('access-check', this.haveAccess,this.teamsList);
  }
```

Comment: `teamsList` is an array. You can not access `teamsList.teamName`. You need to run a loop on the `teamsList` and then access the property `teamName`.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object's property can not be access directly if it is inside an array.
In your code, the `teamsList` variable is an array which is holding 3 items.
Therefore, you can not access the property `teamName` directly on that array.

If your data is dynamic then you need to loop on each time to access its property `teamName`.

```
this.teamsList.forEach(item => {
  if (item.teamName === 'admins') {
     this.haveAccess=true;
     console.log('access-check', item.teamName);
  }
})
```

If your data is fixed which means always an array of 3 items with fixed data then you can access it like this-

```
if (this.teamsList[0].teamName === 'admins') {
   this.haveAccess=true;
   console.log('access-check', this.teamsList[0].teamName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have no errors but when I login with different user (users not in team  'admins'). I can still see the Vue-component.

Answer (score 0):

Put if condition inside `.then` method, also you can remove `async` as you are not using `await`

```
  created() {
      console.log('teams list is before loading teams',this.teamsList);
      this.loadTeams()
      .then((response) => {
        this.teamsList = response.data;
         console.log('teams list is after loadteams',this.teamsList);
         if (this.teamsList.teamName==='admins') {
           this.haveAccess=true
           console.log('access-check',this.teamsList.teamName);
         } 
         console.log('access-check', this.haveAccess,this.teamsList);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can still see the component even with different user, users which are not in team 'admins'. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you might have any number of teams in a `teamsList` array. Hence, correct approach would be to add `haveAccess` property in each object and assign the `true/false` value against this property in each object.

Also, As `teamsList` is an array, you can access it's object properties by iterating it instead of direct access.

Your code should be like this **:**

```
created() {
  this.loadTeams().then((response) => {
    this.teamsList = response.data;
    this.teamsList.forEach(team => {
      team.haveAccess = (team.teamName === 'admins') ? true : false 
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```